# Missing certificate for authenticated push notifications - Dev center

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have converted my WP7 app to WP8. After upload to dev center (Microsoft marketplace center for developers) it says: 
Missing certificate for authenticated push notifications: Certificate for authenticated push notifications

But I have no more options than before. **I have no push notifications in use**.

Any advice what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [check your](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247542%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) **WMAppManifest.xml**  file. Do you have `ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION` defined there?

Comment: Thanks. Problem was, that this flag was set automatically by moving from Windows Phone 7.1 to Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and I did not know if this flag is needed now for any reasons. Error is gone after removing the flag in Visual Studio Manifest.

Comment: @Nasenbaer thanks, your comment should be apart of the answer.